# SqlBulkCopy when column types are unknown

Tags: c#, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy, csvhelper

I am working on a C# app that imports csv data to SQL server. I am using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to achieve this. The use case here is that the app will be used by anyone who wishes to import data from CSV to SQL Server for testing. So CSV files are dynamic.

Now because I have no visibility into the column types, what would be the best way to achieve this? I tried using SqlBulkCopy but I hit a blocker with this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Guid.
System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'.
```

when I am trying to insert a uniqueidenfier.

As I don't have a way to take advantage of column types, I am wondering if there are other options/better ways to achieve this.

Comment: Some value is not Guid in your excel sheet but you’re trying to save in uniqueidentifier column. You can put breakpoint and see the data is matching with the columns or not

Comment: Select the column types from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` ?

Comment: @viveknuna The CSV file is something that I imported from SQL Server directly. I believe everything is saved as a string on the CSV file.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thank you. That's an option. So if I get `uniqueidentifier` as the `DATA_TYPE`, how do I tell SqlBulkCopy to insert it as uniqueidentifier?

Comment: I think you need `IDataRecord.GetFieldType(..) == typeof(Guid)` or `IDataRecord.GetValue(...)` to return the guid. I'm not familiar with `CsvHelper`, but you probably need to extend `CsvHelper.CsvDataReader` to override that method.

Comment: An easy way to get the definition of any table is `SELECT TOP (0) * FROM SomeTable`

Comment: It might easiest to bulk load them into a temp table as all strings and then merge/insert them into the actual table getting sqlserver to do the conversion

Comment: I am contemplating having an in-memory map for SQLServer datatypes => c# types, get the table definition to do something like ```dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(map(uniqueidentifier)))```.  Any drawbacks here? I will keep posted on how it goes.